# Postgresql, how to import large bak.gz file?

Tags: postgresql, import, dump

I have 13GB bak.gz database dump. How can I import it to my local pgsql db by ubuntu command line?

Comment: **what** is a back.gz file? [smells like mysql]

Comment: @wildplasser "BAK is a file extension for a file format typically used when creating a backup copy of a file. Normally, a BAK file is created as an automatic backup when an application is editing or making changes to the file in question. Certain database applications use BAK files when making a backup copy of their database". But my client gave me bak.gz archive

Comment: It is only a convention. The name (or "extension") does not mean anything. Try to look *inside* the file. In unix/linux you could try `file bak.gz`. (the `file` command looks at the file contents and tries to guess what it is)

Comment: @wildplasser, okay, i understand. There is a 2.3GB .bak file inside. Its really weird cause zip is 13GB.

Comment: and command `file bak.gz` returned `Downloads/2020-03-22.bak.gz: gzip compressed data, last modified: Sun Mar 22 19:00:46 2020, from Unix
`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a .gz file inside a .gz file. If you have sufficient disk-space, start by unpacking it:

```
gunzip bak.gz
```

That will probably cause a subdirectory `Downloads` to be created, with a file `2020-03-22.bak.gz` inside it. Now, start again by trying to restore this file.